# Why does C++ list initialization also take regular constructors into account?

Tags: c++, standards, uniform-initialization

In C++ when using initializer_list syntax to initialize an object, the regular constructors of the object also participate in overload resolution, when no other list initialization rule applies.
As far as I understand it, the following code calls X::X(int)

```
class X { int a_; X(int a):a_(a) {} );

void foo() {
   X bar{3};
}
```

But I don't understand, why regular constructors also are considered in context of initializer_lists. I feel that a lot of programmers now write X{3} to call a constructor instead of X(3) to call the construcor.
I don't like this style at all, as it makes me think the object does not have a regular constructor.

What is the reason why the initializer_list syntax can also be used to call regular constructor? Is there a reason to now prefer this syntax over regular constructor calls?

Comment: *"I don't like this style at all, as it makes me think the object does not have a regular constructor"* - I wouldn't call it a language problem.

Comment: The reason is that they wanted to make this syntax work for almost any type. You will find it also works for int and arrays. There is no real reason to prefer the syntax over the old tried and tested syntax if the old one works for you.

Comment: _a lot of programmers now write X{3}_ yes, it‘s uniform initialisation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Essentially it is a mess up. For C++11 it was attempted to create one uniform way to initialize objects instead of multiple approaches otherwise necessary:

- `T v(args...);` for the usual case
- `T d = T();` when using the default constructor for stack-based objects
- `T m((iterator(x)), iterator());` to fight the [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) (note the extra parenthesis around the first parameter)
- `T a = { /* some structured values */ };` for aggregate initialization

Instead the Uniform Initialization Syntax was invented:

```
T u{ /* whatever */ };
```

The intention was that uniform initialization syntax would be used everywhere and the old stule would go out of fashion. Everything was fine except that proponents of initialization from `std::initializer_list<S>` realized that the syntax would be something like that:

```
std::vector<int> vt({ 1, 2, 3 });
std::vector<int> vu{{ 1, 2, 3 }};
```

That was considered unacceptable and uniform initialization syntax was irreparably compromised to allow the *so much better*

```
std::vector<int> vx{ 1, 2, 3 };
```

The problem with this mixture is that it now is sometimes unclear what is actually meant and uniform initialization syntax isn’t uniform any more. It is still necessary in some contexts (especially to value initialize stack-based objects in generic code) but it isn’t the correct choice in all cases. For example, the following two notations were meant to mean the same thing but they don’t:

```
std::vector<int> v0(1, 2); // one element with value 2
std::vector<int> v1{1, 2}; // two elements: 1 and 2
```

tl;dr: initializer list and uniform initialization syntax are the two separate notations. Sadly, they conflict.

Comment: `vu{{ 1, 2, 3 }};` is unacceptable for a c'tor taking a `std::initializer_list`, and yet perfectly okay for an aggregate like `std::array`. Talk about historic blunders.

Comment: Reading this makes me sad. Particularly so since `{1, 2}` has no type, yet in `auto l = {1, 2};` `l` is `std::initializer_list<int>`. Makes me wonder just what problem was being solved by `std::initializer_list`

Comment: I really hate this. If they'd only done something like requiring double braces for init lists, this whole thing would be so much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't like this style at all, as it makes me think the object does not have a regular constructor.

If it's an aggregate type, aggregate initialization is performed. Otherwise, it considers the constructors. If it makes you think that the class is an aggregate, that is not a language problem.

> Is there a reason to now prefer this syntax over regular constructor calls?

If you're a proponent of uniform initialization yes. If you're not, you can stick with the old style. Note that the other answer talks about `std::initializer_list` but this doesn't apply to your question whatsoever, since you have no constructor which takes a `std::initializer_list`. *Braced-init-list*s and `std::initializer_list` are separate concepts. It's best not to get them confused this early on.