# Construct vector of certain size

Tags: c++

Trying to construct a class attribute - a vector of certain size

```
class cTest
{
    public:
    std::vector<double> myTable(1900);
};

main()
{
    cTest test;

    return 0;
}
```

compiler says:

```
./src/main.cpp:43:33: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
   43 |     std::vector<double> myTable(1900);
  |                                     ^~~~
```

Comment: You cannot use parenthesis for a default member initializer. In this case `std::vector<double> myTable = std::vector<double>(1900);` is the correct solution

Comment: Try use:
`std::vector<double> myTable{1900};`

Comment: @prostargamer that will create a vector with a single element (of value `1900.0`)

Comment: @UnholySheep  That seems to work.  It sure looks odd.

Comment: You can also do `= decltype(myTable)(1900)` https://stackoverflow.com/q/48723015/817643 - just choose your flavour of weird

Comment: @ravenspoint, This looks strange because your declaration looks like a method in a class.

Comment: ... or `auto myTable = std::vector<double>(1900);`

Comment: Or initialize the vector at the member initializer list: https://godbolt.org/z/K14cGqd5n. Although, this way, you are creating a user-declared constructor.

Comment: They will probably address this issue in C++23 and if not then in C++26. It's been an annoying issue for quite a while.

Comment: @lorro, `auto` cannot be used in this context.

Comment: @Chris my bad, didn’t notice it’s a member and not a local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
    std::vector<double> myTable(1900);
```

Looks like a member function declaration, and function declarations expect an argument list. `1900` does not satisfy that.

There are a couple of ways to solve this:

```
class cTest
{
    public:
    std::vector<double> myTable = std::vector<double>(1900);
};
```

If you want to make this a little less obnoxiously verbose:

```
class cTest
{
    using dbl_vec = std::vector<double>;

    public:
    dbl_vec myTable = dbl_vec(1900);
};
```

Or using the member initializer list in a constructor:

```
class cTest
{
    public:
    std::vector<double> myTable;

    cTest() : myTable(1900) { }
};
```