# What is the rationale for the way C++ handles uniform initialization with initialization lists?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, uniform-initialization

C++'s uniform initialization syntax fixes the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).  Yay.  But then it introduces [confusion when dealing with initialization lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723164/why-does-stdvectorint-b2-create-a-1-element-vector-and-not-a-2-element).  Boo.  The existing behavior is that:

```
std::vector<int> the_vec{4};
```

will invoke `std::vector(std::initializer_list<T> init)` instead of `std::vector(size_type count);`.

What is the rationale for this decision?  Especially since the language committee was inventing new syntax, it seems to me the other possible designs could have been:

- Require initialization list constructors be invoked by doing `std::vector the_vec = { 4 };`.  Granted, this is no longer "uniform", but it seems conceptually simpler to me to require that *all* initialization list usage use one form, especially when that form matches aggregate initialization of objects in C.
- Require initialization list constructors be invoked by doing `std::vector the_vec{{4}};`.  This also seems conceptually simpler to me.
- Require initialization list constructors be invoked by doing `std::vector the_vec{{4}};` only if `the_vec{4}` would invoke some other constructor.  I don't like this as much since it's hard to tell what constructor is being invoked at the callsite, but at least it would have meant that the old constructor syntax would no longer be necessary.

Comment: Relevant, I think (at least the accepted answer is) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48004905/why-does-c-list-initialization-also-take-regular-constructors-into-account/48005373#48005373

Comment: It's just a matter of getting used to. `std::vector<int> v{4};` making a vector with elements `{4}` and `std::vector<int> v{1, 2};` making a vector with elements `{1, 2}` is totally natural to me, which is why I always use that syntax. Having `std::vector<int> v(4);` create a vector with `{0, 0, 0, 0}` and `std::vector<int> v(1, 2);` create a vector with `{2}` is completely weird and unexpected, so I don't use that syntax for anything. Maybe the rational was to make `std::vector`'s constructors sane.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks.  It doesn't quite explain why the standards committee didn't do something like my third option though.

Comment: @nwp It's not just getting used to. Imagine within a generic context where you expect a type possibly a container being initialized. Which syntax do you use?

Comment: @PasserBy I use `T t{the, params};`. It is simple and obvious. I guess some people are used to the weird constructors and expect them to be called, but since there are 2 ways with different behavior that cannot be helped.

Comment: @nwp *"Cannot be helped"* is great indication there is a problem

Comment: I completely agree with, and wish they'd done literally anything else here, since both list init and uniform init are useful concepts, but both are hampered by looking the same