# Initializing std::vector with curly braces uses initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, constructor

When I replace inner parens with curly braces I get a different result. Why?

Aren't they equivalent after `C++11`? (apart from preventing integer demotion)
Why does it change construction:

from `std::vector(size_type count, const T& value = T(), const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());`

to `std::vector(std::initializer_list<T> init, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());`

**EXAMPLE**

```
auto th_buckets = std::vector<std::vector<int>>{2, std::vector<int>(5, 0)};
```

> 0 0 0 0 0
>
> 0 0 0 0 0

```
auto th_buckets = std::vector<std::vector<int>>{2, std::vector<int>{5, 0}};
```

> 5 0
>
> 5 0

Comment: "Aren't they equivalent after C++11?" No, they aren't. They do different things.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49230097/what-is-the-rationale-for-the-way-c-handles-uniform-initialization-with-initia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they aren't the same, *if* a class has a constructor taking a std::initializer_list, that is preferentially called even if another constructor would fit the initialization list.  std::vector does have one, so the second example creates a list containing [5,0] whereas the second one contains a list of [0,0,0,0,0].

It's generally accepted they messed this part up, sorry!

Comment: I disagree with the mess up.  `{}` always initializes from a list of values.  `()` always calls non-list constructors. Easy-peasy.

Comment: You run into situations like this where the actual behavior depends on whether there's a std::initializer_list constructor though.

Comment: Uniform sometimes not so uniform. Always sucked when someone forgot their sunglasses and everyone had to do without.

Comment: They added the `std::initializer_list` so that `{}` will always initialize from a list of values.  it would be a mistake if `{}` _didn't_ call an initializer list version for a vector.  `{}` should always initialize from a list of values.  It's uniform because now `{}` can uniformly initialize _anythign_ from a list of values, not just PODs.  "uniform" doesn't mean "always use this constructor".